# How to backup a flash drive automatically each time I plug it in?

Tags: windows, backup, usb-flash-drive

I remember using a program to do this in the past, but I can't find it anymore.

Regardless of that, in Windows is there a way I can automatically backup a USB flash drive each time I plug it in?

Comment: Assign the same drive letter to the drive, use a program like GoodSync which will be started, by a Windows Task when the device is detected, then create a job that syncs the files for you.

Comment: Note to people marking down: Please add comments so that everyone can improve. Marking down without comments just puts people off using SU.

Comment: I honestly don't see a problem with this question I understand it would be just like when an Ipod auto syncs with ITunes but ive never used software to auto backup to a pen drive I will look into this myself :) btw +1

Comment: I suspect that @techie007's edit has put it on a better footing. It is when people ask for *recommendations* for software that they get kicked out. Thanks for the +1, hopefully the rewrite will prompt the original downvoter to change their mind.

Answer (score 1):

*Please ask for product recommendations on the appropriate forum [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).*

*Rewrite to match @techie007's edit of the question:*

The easiest way to do an automatic backup when plugging in a USB flash drive is to use a 3rd-party tool such as [Syncback](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/syncback-hub.html). This detects drives being connected and can also detect specific drive ID's and run backups accordingly.

While it is also possible to do this by monitoring Windows Management Interface (WMI) events, I wouldn't recommend it for doing backups as the possibilities for error - and therefore the backup failing - are significant.